# Index name on table does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-migration, ruby-grape

I am using Ruby with grape. I created a migration file to generate a model. When I run the migration file, no error was thrown but the model was not created. So I tried rolling back. since the model does not exit it again throws an error.

```
    class CreatePaymentFortumoInstruments < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table(:payment_fortumo_instruments, id: false) do |t|
          t.primary_key :id, :uuid
          t.string :consumer_id, null: false
          t.string :product_code, null: true, default: nil
          t.string :partner, null: false
          t.string :aasm_state, null: false
          t.datetime :issued_at, null: true
          t.datetime :activated_at, null: true
          t.datetime :deactivated_at, null: true
          t.timestamps
       end

       add_index :payment_fortumo_instruments, :id
      add_index :payment_fortumo_instruments, :consumer_id
    end
   end
```

and the error thrown while rolling back

```
    == 76 CreatePaymentFortumoInstruments: reverting 
   ==============================
   -- remove_index(:payment_fortumo_instruments, 
   {:column=>:consumer_id})
   rake aborted!
  StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations 
  canceled:

 Index name ‘index_payment_fortumo_instruments_on_consumer_id’ on table 
 ‘payment_fortumo_instruments’ does not exist
 /opt/icflix/billing-v2/Rakefile:53:in `block (2 levels) in <top 
 (required)>'
 ArgumentError: Index name 
 ‘index_payment_fortumo_instruments_on_consumer_id’ on table 
 ‘payment_fortumo_instruments’ does not exist
 /opt/icflix/billing-v2/Rakefile:53:in `block (2 levels) in <top 
  (required)>'
 Tasks: TOP => db:rollback
 (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

How can i run the same migration file again and create model. i don't want to create a new migration file for the same.

Comment: Sorry the model name is CreatePaymentFortumoInstruments not CreateTestPaymentFortumoInstruments.

Comment: Delete the last migration record from your schema_migrations table. If your schema.rb file is already generated replace the version number with the previous migration file (The one before CreatePaymentFortumoInstruments). Then run rake db:migrate

Comment: Creating a **table** via a migration will not create an associated **model**. (You don't always *need* a model for a given table!) You need to create that separately, or with some sort of "scaffolding" generator - e.g. [this](https://github.com/icicletech/grape-scaffold#scaffold).

Comment: @VamsiKrishna This works... thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you've messed up your migration and it's a local database, it's always easiest to just drop the database and run migrations again.

If your latest migration updated the schema correctly, you could just run `rake db: reset`, which will recreate the database and then load from the schema.

But to be sure, I'll suggest to re-run migrations: `db:migrate:reset`, which will recreate the database and then run the migrations.

Comment: Thanks, updating the schema_migrations worked for me.